# Show a different image dependent on the value in my ProjectItem in SharePoint Online SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, react

I want to render a different image depending on my value of the project traffic light status. This could be red, yellow or green. If the status is green, I show green and so on.

I don't know where I can write my function and how to use the image URL.

Here is my code so far:

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
let reactcontexthandler = this;
  
   
   console.log("Link zur Seite:" + Webpartprojectsw.websiteurl);
   jquery.ajax({
        url: `${Webpartprojectsw.websiteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectStatusList')/items(1)?$select=Title,ID,StartDate,EndDate,TrafficLight,ProjectPhase/Title&$expand=ProjectPhase`,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose;'},
        success: function (resultData){
          console.log(resultData);
          reactcontexthandler.setState({
          ProjectItem: resultData.d
          
          });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){

        }

   });


}  

public render(): React.ReactElement<IWebpartprojectswProps> {

  const light = this.calculateLight();
  

return (

   <div className={styles.container}>
     <div> {this.state.ProjectItem.Id}</div> 
     <div>{light}</div>

      <div> {this.state.ProjectItem.Title}</div>  
       <div>  {this.state.ProjectItem.StartDate}</div>
       <div>{this.state.ProjectItem.EndDate}</div>
       <div> {this.state.ProjectItem["ProjectPhase"]["Title"]}</div>
       <div> {this.state.ProjectItem.TrafficLight}</div>
        
   </div>      
      
  );

}
```

Do I need to write my function within the render function or somewhere else?

Comment: Where are the image URLs stored, in same list?

Comment: Yes, all the pictures are stored in the same SP Library. Only the ending is different e.g. Green.png etc.

Comment: You can use [Conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) for your requirements. Create an `<img>` tag in render method & set `src` attribute with image URL.